# Trying to install postgis on Centos 6.9 and missing dependency libgeotiff.so.2

Tags: postgresql, centos6, yum, postgis

I'm trying to install Postgis 2.1 on Centos 6.9 (and postgresql 9.5).  I try to yum install it:

```
yum install postgis21_95
```

And get the error:

```
> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg-common)
           Requires: libgeotiff.so.2()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have installed the package: "libgeotiff.x86_64 1.2.5-6.el6" but that doesn't seem to be the right one.

I have very little experience installing packages on linux. I did some web searches and didn't find an answer.

1. What can I do to get it to properly install?

Alternatively:
2. If I don't need the geotiff functionality of postgis, can I safely skip this using "--skip-broken"?

Comment: CentOS 6 has passed end of life. Upgrade to a supported Linux distribution.

Comment: Definitively! You really should not use CentOS 6 [anymore](https://endoflife.software/operating-systems/linux/centos).

Comment: People say the same thing about Drupal 4.  But it works great for my blog!  So should I go with Centos 7?

 Moving the data is going to be a chore (500 GB - 1 TB of tiny files).  It's a low end server with a lot of files.

Comment: I'll try to paraphrase gently: Drupal 4 was great software, just like CentOS 6 was a great operating system. However, it is simply no longer actualized, and thus inevitably security gaps are open. My professional opinion: Having such a system running on the internet is like playing Russian roulette with 6 bullets in the drum. My personal opinion: Of course, you are completely free to do so, but then you also have to live with the unpleasant consequences. (no offence)

Comment: Ok. I'm also going to try if I can get postgis installed on a new Centos 7 server.

Comment: CentOS 7 already reached EOU on 2020-08-06 and will reach EOL on 2024-06-30. CentOS 8 will reach EOL on 2021-12-31. Assuming you don't want to upgrade too often, another Linux distribution which offers long [term support (LTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support) is probably the better option. At the moment, [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) 11 (Bullseye) would be a good choice, as EOS is 2026 and even [ELTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Extended) is offered for Debian releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional packages from ​[EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) 6 (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) are required to fulfill requirements for GDAL. (so enable epel)

However, instead solving this installation challenge on a CentOS 6 installation in 2021, you **really** should consider upgrading the operating system.

Life is strange sometimes: In case there is a reason why upgrading the OS is not a achievable option, [change your repository sources to use the archived versions](https://gcore.de/en/help/linux/centos6-new-repo-url-after-eol.php), as end of 2020 all sources have been removed from mirror servers to reflect the end of life (EOL) status of CentOS6.

Comment: I've got this epel package installed:  epel-release-6-8.noarch 

I tried: yum --enablerepo="epel" install postgis21_95 and get the same error.

When I do yum search epel-release it says "1594 packages excluded due to repository priority protections." Is that a problem?

Comment: Update the repository URL, as described and linked in answer. You are using CentOS 6.9, so use `http://vault.centos.org/6.9/*`. (As already written, installing epel-release-6-8 does not help as end of 2020 all sources have been removed from mirror servers to reflect the EOL status of CentOS6.)

Comment: Ok, thanks!   I followed the instructions in your link.  Now I get:  Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg-common)
           Requires: libnetcdf.so.6()(64bit)

It seems like I might need netcdf 4.1.1 which has that file.  So far I found 4.1.2 at rpmforge, but haven't found 4.1.1.

Comment: There are netcdf packages in the EPEL repository.  The command `yum list netcdf\*` will show you the choices available.

Comment: Ahh I think I needed to disable the rpmreforge.repo. So I did that and now the install worked!